# Dúvida com IF e LISTAS python3

Tags: python

Sou novato na linguagem python, porem comecei desenvolver um script para gerenciar servidores linux etc...
Estou com um probleminha em um trecho do código:

```
def rotear():

    print(" \n Disponível: \n"), os.system("ifconfig|grep eth|cut -c 1-4")
    interface_internet = input(" \n Digite a Interface de Internet: ")
    if interface_internet != ethers[0]:
            print("Nao deu certo!")
```

Seguinte, listei as interfaces de rede, montei esse trecho de código, mas eu queria era arrumar um jeito de pegar a listagem das interfaces de rede, e fazer uma condição verdadeira ou falsa para prosseguir com o código

ex:

> listei a interface com o comando ifconfig | grep eth | cut -c 1-4
>
> eth0
>
> eth1
>
> se interface_internet for diferente de uma das listagens acima, faça isso
>   senão, faça aquilo

Queria uma solução sobre isso...

Coloquei Assim o código:

```
def rotear():
    ethers = ['eth0','eth1','eth2','wlan0','wlan1','ath0','ath1']
    print(" \n Listando Interfaces de Rede(s)..."),time.sleep(1)
    print(" \n Disponível: \n"), os.system("ifconfig|grep eth|cut -c 1-4")
    interface_internet = input(" \n Digite a Interface de Internet: ")
    for device in ethers:
        if interface_internet == device:
            header(" \n 1 - Habilitar Roteamento")
            header(" 2 - Desabilitar Roteamento\n")
            encaminhar = input(" Escolha uma Opção de Roteamento:")
            if encaminhar == "1":
                os.system("echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward")
                os.system("iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o %s -j MASQUERADE" % (interface_internet))
                sucess(" \n Roteamento Habilitado Com Sucesso..."),tcl()
            elif encaminhar == "2":
                os.system("echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward")
                sucess(" \n Roteamento Desabilitado Com Sucesso..."),tcl()
        else:
            fail(" \n Atenção: Valor Inválido. ")
```

só que estou com um problema, se eu colocar o valor: eth2
por exemplo, ele faz dois loops, falando que o valor ta invalido até acertar...
como resolvo isso agora?

Comment: corrige a identação do código fazendo favor

Comment: Para utilizar o python para esse fim, considere utilizar o pacote que sugiro na [minha resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214378/7412)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se voce vai usar o python para tarefas de gerenciamento de infra no ambiente linux, minha sugestão é que faça, antes de tudo; isso:

```
pip install plumbum
```

### [Plubum:](https://plumbum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

([tl;dr](https://anaconda.org/sidon/plumbum_cmds1/notebook))
Com esse pacote vc pode executar a maioria dos comandos shell, para responder sua pergunta, executei um `ifconfig | grep` simples, somente para pegar as linhas em que aparece a string `Eth`, mas vc pode compor o comando que quiser. O resultado do comando é colocado em uma lista e então... Bom... Não vou ficar com muito bla bla bla, pq expliquei [no próprio codigo.](https://anaconda.org/sidon/plumbum_cmds1/notebook)

```
# Para execução de comandos shell
from plumbum.cmd import grep, ifconfig
from plumbum import FG, BG
# Firula
import pprint  

# Monta o comando ifconfig (ifconfig | grep Eth)
ifc = ifconfig | grep["Eth"]

# Executa o comando
f = ifc & BG
output = f.stdout

# Atribui a saida do comando a um objeto tipo lista do pyton
lst = output.splitlines()

pprint.pprint(lst)
```

**Resultado do pprint:**

```
['docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 02:42:bb:5c:52:96  ',
 'enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 10:c3:7b:c4:21:e4  ']
```

**Funções para buscas na lista:**

```
# Pesquisa restritiva, o conteudo da variável tem que "casar" com uma linha inteira na lista
def search1(var):
    return var if var in lst else 'Não encontrado'

# Pesquisa não restritiva, basta uma substring dentro de um dos elementos da lista
def search2(var):
    result = [s for s in lst if var in s]
    return var if len(result)>0 else 'Não encontrado'
```

**Pesquisas na lista:**

```
# Variável a ser pesquisada na lista
str1 = 'docker0'
str2 = 'docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 02:42:bb:5c:52:96  '

print ("REALIZANDO BUSCAS\n")
print ('Busca restritiva')
print ("str1 : ", search1(str1))
print ("str2 : ", search1(str2))
print ('\nBusca não restritiva')
print ("str1 : ", search2(str1))
print ("str2 : ", search2(str2))
```

**Resultados das buscas:**

```
Busca restritiva
str1 :  Não encontrado
str2 :  docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 02:42:bb:5c:52:96  

Busca não restritiva
str1 :  ['docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 02:42:bb:5c:52:96  ']
str2 :  ['docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 02:42:bb:5c:52:96  ']
```

**Utilizando o comando `if`:**

```
if str1 in search1(str1):
    print ('str1 foi encontrada na busca restritiva')
else:
    print ('str1 não foi encontrada na busca restritiva')

if str2 in search1(str2):
    print ('str2 foi encontrada na busca restritiva')
else:
    print ('str2 não foi encontrada na busca restritiva')

if str1 in search2(str1):
    print ('str1 foi encontrada na busca não restritiva')
else:
    print ('str1 não foi encontrada na busca não restritiva')

if str2 in search2(str2):
    print ('str2 foi encontrada na busca não restritiva')
else:
    print ('str2 não foi encontrada na busca não restritiva')
```

**Output para os comandos `if's`:**

```
str1 não foi encontrada na busca restritiva
str2 foi encontrada na busca restritiva
str1 não foi encontrada na busca não restritiva
str2 foi encontrada na busca não restritiva
```

**Consideração final:**
 
Claro que a função `search1(var)` pode ser considerada desnecessária se fossemos considerar somente a busca restritiva, pois bastaria fazer:

```
if var not in lst:
   print ('Não encontrada')
```

Mas dependendo do contexto, pode-se unir as duas funcoes (busca restritiva e não restritiva) em uma só, para ganho de flexibilidade e praticidade.

[Veja o codigo rodando nesse jupyter notebook.](https://anaconda.org/sidon/plumbum_cmds1/notebook)

Comment: Sidon, Muito Obrigado cara, Vou estudar seu código e tentar aplicar ela ao meu código.

Valeu!!!!!

Comment: @AndersonUser777, percebi alguns errinhos e fiz correções no codigo, se for usar o codigo para testes, baixe o notebook direto do anaconda [aqui.](https://anaconda.org/sidon/plumbum_cmds1/notebook)

Comment: Sidon, instalei o plubum com o comando pip install plum, ate ai tudo certo.
mas quando fui executar o script

from plumbum.cmd import grep, ifconfig
ImportError: No module named 'plumbum'

Desde ja agradeço !

Comment: Qual versão do python?

Comment: Blz Sidon, estarei baixando, Baraços...

Comment: Cara estou montando meu código em python3.

Comment: Legal, execute na linha de comando: `python -c "import plumbum; print (plumbum.__version__)"` e cole aqui o resultado.

Comment: Se não aparecer a versão do plumbum, a instalação não obteve sucesso.

Comment: resultado (1, 6, 3)

Comment: uma dúvida vi que a extensão dele é .ipynb
como executo?

Obg...

Comment: Instale o [Jupyter,](http://jupyter.org/) e turbine seu mundo python. :-)  `pip3 install jupyter`

Comment: Há sim Sidon, eu não sabia que era a extensão do jupyter, nunca usei, mas ja vi vários videos explicando sobre, OBG mais uma vez... abraços

Answer (score 3):

Para listar todos as interfaces de rede, pode-se usar o [python-nmap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-nmap). Dê uma procurada para encontrar o comando correto para isso.
Após pegar todas as interfaces, coloque-as numa lista e então use um `for` para testar condições em cada uma das interfaces, algo assim:

```
for device in ethers:
    if interface_internet == device:
        fazer X
    else:
        fazer Y
```

`ethers` será sua lista com todos as interfaces de rede.
O `for` irá fazer um loop para cada interface da lista, o chamando de `device`. Então ele checa se o `device` é igual à `interface_internet`, e ai toma as decisões.

Comment: Bom dia Denis! Muito Obrigado pelo Retorno.
mas tive outro problema, editei o código la em cima.
Desde ja agradeço !

Answer (score 1):

Ele entra 2 vezes no loop e da erro até encontrar porque ele vai testando valor por valor da lista pra ver se eh igual a `'eth2'`. Primeiro testa com `eth0` depois `eth1` e só depois com `eth2`.

Pra verificar se o valor está dentro da lista `ethers` vc deve usar a palavra reservada `in` como eu fiz no codigo abaixo, `if variavel in lista:...`.

```
def rotear():
    ethers = ['eth0','eth1','eth2','wlan0','wlan1','ath0','ath1']
    print(" \n Listando Interfaces de Rede(s)..."),time.sleep(1)
    print(" \n Disponível: \n"), os.system("ifconfig|grep eth|cut -c 1-4")
    interface_internet = input(" \n Digite a Interface de Internet: ")
    if interface_internet in ethers:
        header(" \n 1 - Habilitar Roteamento")
        header(" 2 - Desabilitar Roteamento\n")
        encaminhar = input(" Escolha uma Opção de Roteamento:")
        if encaminhar == "1":
            os.system("echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward")
            os.system("iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o %s -j MASQUERADE" % (interface_internet))
            sucess(" \n Roteamento Habilitado Com Sucesso..."),tcl()
        elif encaminhar == "2":
            os.system("echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward")
            sucess(" \n Roteamento Desabilitado Com Sucesso..."),tcl()
    else:
        fail(" \n Atenção: Valor Inválido. ")
```

Comment: Corrigido o nome..rsrs...perdão
Valeu Gabriel, Agora Deu certo!!
Muito Obrigado, depois vou ver um jeito de tentar colocar a listagem do comando ifconfig dentro da lista ou lago assim.

Muito Grato!

Comment: é gabriel meu nome hahaha.

Comment: que bom que conseguiu cara, mete ficha ai!

Comment: Corrigindo o Nome: Valeu "Gabriel"... rsrs... desculpa pela gafe.... MUITO OBRIGADO.

Comment: @AndersonUser777, para colocar o resultado do comando `ifconfig` dentro de uma lista python, veja [minha resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214378/7412)

Comment: @Sidon estou olhando para o código que passou agora!
Muito Obrigado pela ajuda..