# Subprocess & call em Python ( Segurança )

Tags: python, segurança, biblioteca

Desenvolvendo uma aplicação simples, algumas ferramentas de análise de código me deram o seguinte aviso :

> Consider possible security implications associated with call module.

Para esse determinado trecho de código : `from subprocess import call`, e mais abaixo também nesse trecho `call ( '...', shell = True )`, tentei com `shell = false` e não funcionou, a chamada deste método no programa é realizada com argumento do tipo string e não lista, porém nesse caso testei com uma lista de argumentos também.

Pelo que sei sobre importação, escopo dos símbolos e desempenho essa seria a melhor forma de importar já que vou estar usando somente está função, estou certo ?

Lendo esse trecho da documentação :

> If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed without specifying any arguments.

Percebi que mesmo a utilização estando insegura, a implementação está correta, porém lendo um pouco mais só me gerou mais dúvidas, ' Se o shell for True, o comando especificado será executado através do shell ', e se ele não for igual a `true` ... onde vai ser executado ?

Ps : ' Se args for uma string, a interpretação é dependente da plataforma e descrita abaixo. ' ( Isso é sobre o `Popen`, o mesmo vale para `call` ? )

Existe alguma forma de deixar a utilização do método `call` com argumento do tipo `string` segura ? ( Ou vou ter de usar `Popen` que acredito ser basicamente a mesma coisa só que com mais argumentos - estou perguntando em parte por curiosidade )

Comment: Já tentou o plumbum? veja se faz sentido [nessa resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214378/7412)

Comment: Opá, vou testar aqui, não conhecia ele - vlw pela dica.