# Como enviar multiplos comandos para um servidor remoto usando python

Tags: python

Como posso enviar multiplos comandos para um servidor remoto usando python?

Eu tive de aprender python por motivos de estudo, decidi então tentar automatizar a coleção de informação dos consoles bacula.

Estou tentando usando o seguinte script, mas não tenho tido sucesso.

Poderiam me apontar onde estou errando?

```
HOST= 'server.name.com.br'

try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = HOST 
    username = 'root'
    password = 'xxxxxxx' 
    s.login(hostname, username, password)
    s.sendline('bconsole')   # run a command
    s.prompt()               # match the prompt
    print(s.before)          # print everything before the prompt.
    s.prompt()               # match the prompt
    s.sendline('st')   # run a command
    s.prompt()               # match the prompt
    print(s.before)          # print everything before the prompt.
    s.prompt()               # match the prompt
    s.sendline('1')   # run a command
    s.prompt()               # match the prompt
    print(s.before)          # print everything before the prompt.
    s.prompt()               # match the prompt

    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
    print("pxssh failed on login.")
```

Muito obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Qual é o problema? alguma msg de erro? a pergunta está um tanto obscura, pq esta usando o pxssh? ssh não seria suficiente e mais simples? Conhece o [plubum?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214378/7412) e  o [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. O que acontece é que ele executa apenas o primeiro comando. ele abre o Bconsole, mas os comandos posteriores não executam. Ficando parado naquela parte do script. da esses erros aqui

Comment: Sobre o fabric, eu li sobre ele, mas achei que seria mais util o pxssh por não depender de nada externo ao python... talvez eu estivesse errado.

Comment: Pois é, fabric é feito em python, e não vc nao vai precisar instalar nada no remoto. Faço depoloy django, sincroização de banco postrgres, e até limpeza de logs em um servidor google, tudo via fabric. Show de bola. Plumbum tb é outro a se considerar.